# How to do delete operation in database using checkbox?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I tried to delete multiple items from database using check box using node.js.But if any one of the check box is true everything is true.How to get this?
here the checkbox value for each item is not getting passed.
how to solve this.

```
router.post('/del', function (req, res, next) {
  mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);



    var cursor = db.collection('log').find();
    cursor.forEach(function (doc, err) {

      var id2 = Boolean(req.body.chk);



      db.collection('log').findAndModify({ "option": id2 }, function (err, result) {
        if (result) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          console.log('Item updated');
          resultArray4.push(id2);
          console.log(resultArray4);
          var id3 = id2;
          id2 = null;
          db.collection('log').deleteMany({ "option": id3 }, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Item deleted');
          });
        } else {
          res.render('check');
        }
       });
    }); 
  }); res.render('check');
   resultArray4.length = 0;
   id2 = id3 = null; count = 0;
 });
```

Handlebars code ....here the checkbox value for each item is not getting passed.
how to solve this.

```
<div class="deletedd">
    <table class="table-table-bodered" border="auto" style="solid">

        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Author</th><br><br>
        <th>Select</th>

        <div>
            {{#each items }}

            <tr>
                <article class="item">
                    <td>{{ this.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ this.number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ this.address }}</td>

                    <td>
                        <form action="/checkss/del" method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>

                </article>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </div>

    </table>
</div>

<button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the problem with saving the data to the db or with getting unexpected data posted to your Node server?

Comment: the problem is with the check box.it is not checking for each item in the database.if any of the check box is on it gives true for all.i want to delete selected item from database using check box.

Comment: Maybe if id3 is an object, when you write id2=null, that makes id3 null also and so deleteMany has no filter so deletes all.  Print id3 before deleteMany and put that output in the question.  If it is not null, you will need to post your HTML form code.

Comment: I have added my hbs.

Comment: like I said, you need to print id3 before the deleteMany call and put that information in your question.  Need to verify it is not null.

Comment: id3 also shows true.if any one of the check box is on.